# Grouping field in tabs

Tags: 7, views, blocks

When I select unformatted settings and can Grouping field, it is working fine. Now I am using Bootstrap tabs, but it is not working.

How we can do this?

Comment: Have you tried: [Views Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap)

Comment: when i use tabs behaviout, it doesnot allow me to do group by

Comment: This is related and shows how to achieve this - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161320/is-there-a-way-to-use-grouping-settings-for-bootstrap-tabs-in-views

Answer (score 0):

For using Bootstrap tabs with views you need to use the [Views Bootstrap module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap): Views Boostrap module enables you to create components following the theme structure of the Bootstrap framework all within the configuration settings of the powerful Views module.

Views Bootstrap module supports following:

- List item
- Grid
- Tables
- Thumbnail
- Media object
- Accordion
- Carousel
- Tabs
- **List group**

Comment: when i use tabs behaviout, it doesnot allow me to do group by